# Book for Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, book-recommendation

Which book either on functional analysis or specifically for Hilbert spaces has the best way of explaining with most examples and to the point without much applications. I studied Limaye's book and Kreyszig's book but all the books on functional analysis are too clumsy for me. I want to mainly study eigenspectrums, and compact operators and Hilbert spaces for an exam. So any book, that will help me through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introduction to Hilbert Spaces by Debnath is very solid and readable.

Same title by N Young is worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Debnath book is solid. It has all i want...

Comment: Does that answer the question for you?

Comment: It did. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

My choice will be

Introduction to Topology and Functional Analysis by Goerge F. Simmons. You will definitely get the topics which have been mentioned here. The author provides a very simple yet elegant approach

Comment: I've read its first 50 pages. It does seem that the author focus on intuition, but it still has less graphic than I expected, perhaps because it was written when modern computer hasn't existed (1963). I am looking for an inspiring book like "Visual Complex Analysis" of Needham.